# Can you offset keyframes of instances?

Tags: animation, instances

Hey everyone I am just trying to figure out a little problem... I have this looping animation where a ball comes out of a tube and goes in the other side.

In this scene I have made 4 instances of the original collection with the animation, I am curious if it is possible to offset the keyframes to these instances so you get a nice variation between them ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the instances being created from? Particles, Vertices? You could create separate particle instances and offset their creation. I'm a bit confused at whats going on here I'm afraid.

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: Perhaps I am making it more complicated than it need be. Basically if I keyframe a cube put it in a collection and then instance it .... would it be possible to offset the keyframes of that instance?